# Only 1 out of 2 ChartJS i showing

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have wanna show 2 charts on the same page.

```
<div class="row">
<div>
  <canvas id="users" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div>
  <canvas id="yardsChart" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
const labels = [
    "08-07","09-07","10-07","11-07","12-07","13-07","14-07","15-07"
];
const labels_2 = [
    "08-07","09-07","10-07","11-07","12-07","13-07","14-07","15-07"
];
                                    
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Ny brugere',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [95,92,111,114,143,134,114,55],
    }]
};
const data2 = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Nye haver',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [2,3,8,3,7,12,5,1],
    }]
};
                                    
const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {}
};
const config_2 = {
    type: 'bar',
    data2,
    options: {}
};
                                    
var myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('users'),
    config
);
var myChart_2 = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('yardsChart'),
    config_2
);
```

But only the first one is visible. If I change data2 to just data, then I get 2 charts that are equal. What is wrong with data2 ?
I have tried to the the order of the canvas', but no difference.

Comment: do you have any console hints/errors ?

Comment: only possible mistake i see is that in data2 u are using `labels` instead of `labels_2` but i dont see why this could be an issue

Comment: Unfortunately no console hints. And I use same labels for both charts. And if I use "data" for both charts everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in js if you put a variable in an object without specifying the key it will take the name of the variable as the key. Chart.js expects a key `data` for the data and not `data2` so if you write your second config like so it will work:

```js
const config_2 = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data2,
    options: {}
};
```

Live example to demonstrate issue:

```js
const text = "hiii";

const data = {
  text
};

const data2 = {
  data: text
};

console.log(data);
console.log(data2);
```